# Identifying stops from telemetric data using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have telemetric (latitude, longitude, time, mileage) from a large number of vehicles. Each pandas dataframe has one vehicle's travel over time and I would like to identify when the vehicle stops.

I have used pandas groupby to identify if the vehicle is moving between rows (accounting for some drift).

`df['Stopped'] = (df.groupby('DAY')['LAT'].diff() <= 0.0001) & (df.groupby('DAY')['LNG'].diff() <= 0.0001)`

This is not flagging the stops accurately though. Here is a bit where the vehicle is clearly moving (sorry its in HTML code - I don't know how to get it to format as a table otherwise).

```html
       Stopped      LAT       LNG         DAY
401218     True  22.6874  113.9487  2018-10-15
401219     True  22.6874  113.9487  2018-10-15
401220     True  22.6874  113.9487  2018-10-15
401221     True  22.6873  113.9487  2018-10-15
401222     True  22.6869  113.9483  2018-10-15
401223     True  22.6863  113.9479  2018-10-15
401224     True  22.6859  113.9476  2018-10-15
401225     True  22.6854  113.9471  2018-10-15
401226     True  22.6849  113.9468  2018-10-15
401227     True  22.6844  113.9463  2018-10-15
401228     True  22.6841  113.9457  2018-10-15
401229     True  22.6839  113.9449  2018-10-15
401230     True  22.6838  113.9438  2018-10-15
401231     True  22.6837  113.9428  2018-10-15
401232     True  22.6837  113.9417  2018-10-15
401233     True  22.6836  113.9409  2018-10-15
401234     True  22.6835  113.9400  2018-10-15
401235     True  22.6833  113.9392  2018-10-15
401236     True  22.6832  113.9387  2018-10-15
401237     True  22.6832  113.9384  2018-10-15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the output of `df.groupby('DAY')['LAT'].diff()`. Many values are negative, so you need to take the absolute value before you check if they are less than your cutoff value:

```
df['Stopped2'] = (df.groupby('DAY')['LAT'].diff().abs() <= 0.0001) & (df.groupby('DAY')['LNG'].diff().abs() <= 0.0001)
print(df)
```

```
        Stopped      LAT       LNG       DAY  Stopped2
401218     True  22.6874  113.9487  10/15/18     False
401219     True  22.6874  113.9487  10/15/18      True
401220     True  22.6874  113.9487  10/15/18      True
401221     True  22.6873  113.9487  10/15/18      True
401222     True  22.6869  113.9483  10/15/18     False
401223     True  22.6863  113.9479  10/15/18     False
401224     True  22.6859  113.9476  10/15/18     False
401225     True  22.6854  113.9471  10/15/18     False
401226     True  22.6849  113.9468  10/15/18     False
401227     True  22.6844  113.9463  10/15/18     False
401228     True  22.6841  113.9457  10/15/18     False
401229     True  22.6839  113.9449  10/15/18     False
401230     True  22.6838  113.9438  10/15/18     False
401231     True  22.6837  113.9428  10/15/18     False
401232     True  22.6837  113.9417  10/15/18     False
401233     True  22.6836  113.9409  10/15/18     False
401234     True  22.6835  113.9400  10/15/18     False
401235     True  22.6833  113.9392  10/15/18     False
401236     True  22.6832  113.9387  10/15/18     False
401237     True  22.6832  113.9384  10/15/18     False
```